# vb 2010 InvalidCastException error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a simple access db login form and have received the error above when running. This only happens if the user combo is correct. If the login is incorrect, then the invalid message is shown. But if I supply the correct credentials then this error is thrown. Can someone enlighten me as to exactly what this error means. It mentions 'conversion from string "BT" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.' where 'BT' is the correct username.

```
Private Sub login_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
        ' If txtLogin.Text = "1" And txtPassBox.Text = "1" Then
        ' Form2.Show()
        ' Me.Hide()


        ' Else : MsgBox("Sorry, That combination is not recognised.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Invalid Data Supplied")

        ' End If

        Dim user As String
        Dim password As String

        user = txtLogin.Text
        password = txtPassBox.Text

        If Me.UserTableAdapter.ScalarQueryLogin(user, password) Then
            MessageBox.Show("You have logged in")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("You have supplied the wrong combo")
        End If

    End Sub
```

sql query:

```
SELECT        [User], [Password]
FROM            [User]
WHERE        ([User] = ?) AND ([Password] = ?)
```

Comment: Just change the query to `SELECT  count(*) FROM [User]
WHERE ([User] = ?) AND ([Password] = ?)`  then it should cast to a boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your ScalarQueryLogin method returns a string, and you are using it as if it were a Boolean.

EDIT:
It would be easier to troubleshoot this if you told us what type your ScalarQueryLogin method returns.  Anyways, try something like this:

```
Private Sub login_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
        ' If txtLogin.Text = "1" And txtPassBox.Text = "1" Then
        ' Form2.Show()
        ' Me.Hide()


        ' Else : MsgBox("Sorry, That combination is not recognised.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Invalid Data Supplied")

        ' End If

        Dim user As String
        Dim password As String

        user = txtLogin.Text
        password = txtPassBox.Text

        If Me.UserTableAdapter.ScalarQueryLogin(user, password) IsNot Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("You have logged in")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("You have supplied the wrong combo")
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Douglas How am I using it as a boolean? I set a sql query which builds ok with no errors. I am newbie to VB coming from PHP background.

Comment: In your If statement.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard for me to completely answer the question because there is a lot of data missing, but from the error and context I would say that `ScalarQueryLogin` is returning a string (specifically it is returning `user`.  Without seeing that actual query that is being made it is hard to know for sure. I would suggest maybe something like this:

```
Dim resultValue as Object

resultValue = Me.UserTableAdapter.ScalarQueryLogin(user, password)

If resultValue Then
...
```

This will allow you to step through and get a better idea of what your query is returning and may provide you with more insight about the problem.

Comment: you may want to consider a more secure logon in general, using something like hashes instead of storing users passwords, but to solve the problem at hand, you could try a query like this:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [User] WHERE ([User] = ?) AND ([Password] = ?)`

Then you can do a `If resultValue > 0 Then` comparison since the query will be returning an integer and not the user name that is passed in.

Comment: There is no query mageos. Thanks

Comment: I am a bit confused because I followed a tutorial on youtube and they took the COUNT(*) out of the statement and there query ran ok. I am just trying to understand the logic. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 this link will be helpful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171902.aspx